# How to change a post category when the ACF datepicker Field is today

Tags: categories, custom-field, wp-cron

I hope someone can help me for this:

I have posts in an "event" category and an ACF datepicker Field named "expiration".
I'd like those posts to automatically go to the "past-event" category when the "expiration" field is reached.

I tried this with Post Expirator Plugin but it seems that the plugin is no longer working.

I also tried using the code on this [page](https://multiplestates.wordpress.com/2016/01/06/scheduling-a-category-change-based-on-an-advanced-custom-field-value-when-a-post-is-saved-using-a-wordpress-cron-job/)
and changed it a bit and it's now working but only changes the category when we manually save the post, so it doesn't really do the job. I'd like it to automatically change when the "expiration" field is today.

I would really appreciate some help on this !